# Why doesn't anyone have the beta badge?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges, beta

I noticed that there are 0 users that earned the [Beta Badge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta).  Anyone know why there are 0 users that earned the badge?  I googled for it and found some answers like [this one from Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19), but it still isn't obvious to me what the criteria is for it (i.e., what does "Actively" mean) or when it gets awarded.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it only gets awarded once the site gets out of the public beta phase?

Comment: Strange that it specifically states that it is for private beta participation, though.  I would have thought it would have been awarded during private beta or directly after private beta.

Comment: Yay, I think your question triggered something ! Just now: 
 "37 Users earned this badge."

Comment: See?! META WORKS!!!

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awarding of beta badges is triggered manually at some point during the private beta - [37 users now have this badge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta).

#### Background

You become eligible for the beta badge once the site moves into public beta, assuming you meet the requirements outlined below:

> #### Beta
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Participate actively in a site's private beta phase
>     *Historically, active participation meant earning at least three bronze badges, but the exact requirements are no longer disclosed to prevent users from doing just the bare minimum.*
> - Not awarded on Meta sites, including Meta Stack Overflow

From [**List of all badges with full descriptions**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399)

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, Robert. Our site has been in public beta for a while so hopefully you can understand our confusion as to why nobody earned it. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta

Comment: @MikeChale I'm checking into it now.

Comment: Thank you for fixing this!

Comment: Thanks! This is now the badge I am most proud of

Comment: Shame I only stumbled upon SFSE a few months ago, would've loved that beta badge :)